# How to iterate through json arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm stuck in a script here, not sure how to get it to print in the div I set up.  I imagine it's something related to how I'm handling the response. 
The response in chrome devtools looks like this:

```
{
    "[\"record one\", \"/description\"]": 0
}
```

I've attempted to use both each and map to iterate the data out but so far not going anywhere.  I'm brand new to js and jquery, so the script is mostly from reading and examples.

Maybe some kind of nested loop? Here is my code -

```
 $(function() {
  return $('#myslider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    values: [1, 20],
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var max, min;
      min = ui.values[0];
      max = ui.values[1];
      $('#range').text(min + ' - ' + max);
      $.ajax({
        url: '/dir_scan',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
          min: min,
          max: max
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          var albums;
          albums = response;
          $.each(albums, function(index, obj) {
            var albumname, artist, li_tag;
            li_tag = '';
            albumname = obj.AlbumName;
            artist = obj.Artist;
            li_tag += '<li>Artist: ' + artist + ', Album: ' + albumname + '</li>';
            $('#result').append($(li_tag));
            return console.log;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you screwed up the translation of your json... can you [edit] and fix? Please cut out all the record name guff--we don't care that it contains "pink Floyd yadda yadda" you can substitute shorter strings like `{ ["record 1", "description 1"] : 1 }`. Also, verify the format of the json is exactly how you're getting it, because what you have in your question appears fubar.

Comment: Why albums id the anchor part or your URL? I believe the loop should be over the returned response in the success function...

Comment: The return is a hash of arrays before the server sends it as json.  Looks like this in the response tab `{"[\"record1\", \"/descripton"]":0,....."}`

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Try: https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: jsonlint.com says **valid**, on the code I posted a few comments up, from the response tab.  I think I botched the string in the comment.  If I put the actual response in, it's valid.

Comment: `{
 ["record", "description"]: 1, …
}
["record1", "description"]:
1
 ["record2", "description"]:
 2["record3", "description"]` **invalid**. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how iteration worked for this situation.  Comments in code -

```
success: function(response) {
  var albums;
   // side issue - but I had to clear the div to get a complete refresh
    $('#result').empty();
      albums = response;
        $.each(albums, function(key, value) {
          var albumname, li_tag, path;
          li_tag = '';
        // I found I had to do this parseJSON call otherwise 
        // I had no correct key/value pair, even though I had set dataType 
        // to JSON
        albumname = jQuery.parseJSON(key);
      path = albumname[1];
    li_tag += '<li ><a href=/album' + encodeURI(albumname[1]) + '>' + albumname[0] + '</a href></li>';
  $('#result').append($(li_tag));
 return console.log;
 });
```

Actually, `value` in the code is just the index number, but I had the actual key/value pair separated by commas, so again the parseJSON seemed to be the only way it would work. This, despite trying things like split and substr.  Hope my answer is clear if not I can edit.

Answer (score 2):

As Will said in the comments, the JSON looks off.

But, you're on the right track of using .each, as it looks that you're returning an array of objects.

Here's an example of what to do:

```
    var li_tag = '';
    $.each(albums, function(index, obj) {
        var albumname = obj.AlbumName;
        var artist = obj.Artist
        li_tag += '<li>Artist: ' + artist + ', Album: ' + albumname + '</li>';
        $('#result').append($(li_tag));
        return console.log;
    });
```

Additionally, 'albums' should be set to the returned response of the success function. You're potentially creating a bunch of headache to try and decipher from the window.location; especially since the json example looks malformed. And, any work done with the data returned from the ajax call, should occur in the success function.

Comment: I believe you put me on the right track.  I did set albums to the response, but am getting `artist` and `albumname` as undefined.  I realize you gave me an example, but I believe these are arbitrary names anyway.

Comment: The problem with the answer is it didn't take into account that my server and json data is not keyed in that manner.  Each key / value is unique so I have nothing to reference for a key or to break the obj apart. Each key/value pair though is separated by a comma.  I had a run with trying `split()` with no success but will have a run at it again.

Comment: @stuartambient . The example is merely that, an example, with generic names given the obj name, though, the idea is still valid. You'll have access to each item in the obj, and can do what you need to each. With what you're expecting back, you may want to use a $.map() within the $.each, and $.map the objs iterated in the $.each. This will give you simple access to each key/value pair in the obj.

Comment: I probably should have phrased my prior comment better.  Apologies, what I meant was there was no way to reference the elements in the json array.  That threw me some for a while till I actually tried `obj` (from your example) with no index element.